# How to tie up my app's version number with the build in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode, version

I am using Xcode 4.2 now. I wonder if there is a way to update my app's version (subversion) number each time I build the app. So for example, now it's 1.5.17, and then after a build, it'll be changed to 1.5.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment the build number by an sh script.

Click on **Build Phase** in your Project Target then **Add Run Script** and add the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" MYPROJECTDIR/MYPROJECTDIR-Info.plist)
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" MYPROJECTDIR/MYPROJECTDIR-Info.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @WrightsCS is perfectly fine if you want to roll your own solution. If you want to try out how **Apple** does it internally, check out [Automating Version and Build Numbers Using agvtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html).